# QT - Class For Connecting to Mqtt Broker With QMqttClient

Tags: c++, pointers, qt

**Task:**

Class for connecting to a mqtt broker using `QMqttClient` and getting notified on `connect` and `disconnect`.

**Context:**

I'm trying to write modern C++ (standard 2011 and up) code - using smart pointers. I have only created small projects for learning C++. I'm not very confident if I'm using those pointers correctly.

**The implementation:**

The implementation is in the `client.h` and `client.cpp` header file. The first code snippet is the `client.h` one.

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H

#include <QString>
#include <QObject>
#include <QtMqtt/QtMqtt>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct MqttConfig {
    MqttConfig() {
        hostname = "localhost";
        port = 1883;
    }

    QString hostname;
    quint16 port;
};

struct SubscriptionConfig
{
    SubscriptionConfig() = delete;
    SubscriptionConfig(QString t, quint16 q) :
        topic(t), qos(q)
    {}

    QString topic;
    quint16 qos; // quality of service
};

class Client : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    std::unique_ptr<QMqttClient> mqtt;
    std::unique_ptr<MqttConfig> c;

public:
    Client();
    void connectToSignals();
    void configureClient(std::unique_ptr<MqttConfig>&);
    void connect();

public slots:
    void onConnected()
    { std::cout << "Connected to mqtt broker " << std::endl; }
    void onDisconnected()
    { std::cout << "Disconnected from mqtt broker" << std::endl; }
};

#endif // CLIENT_H
```

Am I violating the `DRY` principle (don't repeat yourself) in the method `connectToSignals` ? And how could I avoid this?

```
#include "client.h"

Client::Client()
{
    mqtt = std::make_unique<QMqttClient>();
    c = std::make_unique<MqttConfig>();
    configureClient(c);
    connectToSignals();
    connect();
}

void Client::connectToSignals()
{
    QObject::connect(Client::mqtt.get(), &QMqttClient::connected, this,
                     &Client::onConnected);
    QObject::connect(Client::mqtt.get(), &QMqttClient::disconnected, this,
                     &Client::onDisconnected);
}

void Client::configureClient(std::unique_ptr<MqttConfig>& c)
{
    mqtt->setHostname(c->hostname);
    mqtt->setPort(c->port);
}

void Client::connect()
{
    mqtt->connectToHost();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Qt-ness

My QT is a little bit rusty, but you're probably not doing the right thing here. First `QObject` have their own memory management, usually each `QObject` constructor takes a `parent`, this parent takes ownership of the created object. As the `setParent()` function is always available, interfering with the memory management via `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` is usually not a good idea.

Additionally you are containing `QMQTTClient` for what looks like just configuration reasons, there really doesn't seem to be any need to wrap it in another layer, you might as well just replace your client with `QMQTTClient` and connect to it. If you want to wrap configuration, a free function will do with much less overhead.

#### Stack-vs-Heap

Both the `QMQTTClient` and the `MQTTConfig` could as well be stack allocated, making everything easier. Passing `MQTTConfig` by reference will work well enough.

#### `MQTTConfig`

The constructor should use initializer lists and not the function body for member variable initialization.

```
MqttConfig() : hostname("localhost"), port(1883) {}
```

I'd probably prefer default values for this,

```
MqttConfig(QString h = "localhost", qint16 p = 1883  ) : hostname(h), port(p) {}
```

### SubscriptionConfig

The default constructor doesn't need to be deleted if you are defining a custom constructor